# Magento 2.4.2 opensearch error

Tags: magento2, opensearch

I'm using opensearch and I'm getting the following error on the category page. I'm also getting a similar error during indexing.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception): {"error":"no handler found for uri [/magento2_product_1/document/_search] and method [POST]"}
```

I'm using brew for opensearch, the version is 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per system requirements from Magento official, Magento currently does not support Opensearch 2.x, it only supports Opensearch 1.2 for Magento version >=2.4.3-p2 (but in real life, you can use 1.3.4 or 1.3.6 as well).

So, I'm not sure Opensearch works on 2.4.2 or not, but you should use Opensearch 1.2 instead of 2.x

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: Not the easiest job to downgrade on mac using brew, but it is what it is. Thank you

Comment: @kotsios would you mind sharing how you did it though?

Comment: hey @LouisB., I ended up uninstalling everything related to elasticsearch and opensearch and install Elasticsearch again. If I'm not mistaken I've followed these instructions: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html